# Angular Subdomain

Tags: angular, angular6, subdomain

I am trying to create a subdomain in angular 6 using the below method.

**For example:**
localhost:4200 
client1.localhost:4200 
client2.localhost:4200

```
  getSubdomain() {
    const domain = window.location.hostname;
    if (domain.indexOf('.') < 0 
       || domain.split('.')[0] === 'example' 
       || domain.split('.')[0] === 'lvh' 
       || domain.split('.')[0] === 'www') {
       this.subdomain = '';
    } else {
       this.subdomain = domain.split('.')[0];
    }
    console.log('subdomain', this.subdomain);
  }
```

1. When running the command 'ng serve --disable-host-check' it's working fine. But this is not secure way.
2. 'Invalid Host Header' error message is displayed, when the command 'ng serve' is ran.

Kindly suggest me any other option to create a subdomain in angular 6.

Comment: domain handling should not happen in Angular. In fact your frontend webapp should be domain agnostic. In your local dev env it doesn't matter otherwise look into different static hosting solutions and use DNS settings for handling subdomains

Comment: actually we are handling subdomain using nodejs in server side using routes53 in aws but we need to use angular for fast application , can you look at this in this way

Comment: It's just something you can't do. It's out of the reach of javascript to modify the domain. The only thing you can do is redirect - but you're responsible to serve that content from that subdomain.

Answer (score 3):

For development purpose you can add sub domain in etc/host file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) like below.

```
127.0.0.1       client1
::1         client1
127.0.0.1       client2
::1         client2
```

Serve application by using command:-

```
ng serve --host client1 --port 4300 --open
ng serve --host client2 --port 4400 --open
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply.. Its not static. Subdomain will generate dynamically.

Comment: What do you need. We cannot add domain names dynamically at client side.

Comment: if user enters vinod.stackflow.com ,then we have to render that user name vinod from domain,thats it,we done this through nodejs but need to do that in angular